# How to show spinner dropdown full screen?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I want to show spinner full screen..I reached i didnot get proper solution.

**XML**

```
<Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/spinner_style"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appbarlayouts"
        android:overlapAnchor="false"
        android:id="@+id/task_spinner"></Spinner>
```

**Java**

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, categories) {

            @Override
            public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            {
                View v = null;
                v = super.getDropDownView(position, null, parent);
                // If this is the selected item position

                if (position == selectedItem) {
                    v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
                }
                else {
                    // for other views
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                   // ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(position)).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                }

                return v;
            }
        };  // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        task_spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

**My output**
 I want to show drop down upto bottom view but currently it's not showing

[image]

Comment: if you want to show its option in separate full screen view try setting `android:spinnerMode="dialog"` if its fine with you.

Comment: @KaranMer bro i didnot want to use dialog

Comment: are you sure you have overflowing items?

Comment: you can design textview with design you created. you can then show/hide recyclerview with items that matches parent height when you click on arrow or selected textview.

Comment: @KaranMer Thanks for your suggestion,i got a idea..it's helped me